# Cannot add more than one ec2 instances to AWS ELB using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have successfully provision the AWS infrastructure using terraform.

While attaching more than one instance (multiple instances) to AWS ELB, I am able to attach the instances using Autoscaling.

```
resource "aws_elb" "abc-ext-elb" { name = "${var.galaxy}-abc-ext-elb" listener { } listener { } listener { } } security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.xxxx}"] subnets = ["${xxxxx}"] instances = ["${aws_instance.myinstance.id}"]
```

And also I have tried like:

```
"instances = "${element(aws_instance.mqttcluster.id, count.index)}"
```

In both the cases it did not work

But while adding the instances without auto scaling, only one instance I am able to add using terraform, I am not able to add more than one instance 
 from same group of instances. How to solve this issue? I did not find any module for this.

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 1):

How did you define your elb? it should be something like this:

```
resource "aws_elb" "my-elb" {
    ...
    instances = ["${aws_instance.myinstances.*.id}"]
    ...
}
```

Comment: resource "aws_elb" "abc-ext-elb" {
  name = "${var.galaxy}-abc-ext-elb"

  listener {
    
  }

  listener {
    
  }
  listener {
    
  }
  
  }

security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.xxxx}"]
  subnets = ["${xxxxx}"]
   instances = ["${aws_instance.myinstance.id}"]

Comment: resource "aws_elb" "abc-ext-elb" {
  name = "${var.galaxy}-abc-ext-elb"

  listener {
    
  }

  listener {
    
  }
  listener {
    
  }
  
  }

security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.xxxx}"]
  subnets = ["${xxxxx}"]
   instances = ["${aws_instance.myinstance.id}"]

Comment: And also I have tried like "instances = "${element(aws_instance.mqttcluster.id, count.index)}"   like also . In both the cases it did not work.

Comment: If you have many instances of a resource this should work `aws_instance.myinstances.*.id`. Check out the answer

Comment: Thanks for response Julio. I will try now and let you know

Comment: Hi Sir, I have tested. After modified  as you suggested, it is working fine as expected.

Answer (score 1):

just remove [] from instances and it should

```
instances = ["${aws_instance.myinstances.*.id}"]
```